# ag Grid not showing data untill all grid events get finished

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid

I have set rowData in `onGridReady` but it does not show data until all events are finished. I have tried `firstCellrendered` event as well but no luck

```
OnGridReady(){
   this.rowdata= somedata;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
OnGridReady(params) {
  params.api.setRowData(somedata); 
}
```